# Can't seem to get gdb working on my mac

Tags: macos, gcc, gdb

I've been trying to get gdb working on my mac, but alas. Here's the issue log.

```
| => gdb ./src admin
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./src...Reading symbols from /Users/home/CTCI-C/Chapter1/1.1/src.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/src...done.
done.
/Users/home/CTCI-C/Chapter1/1.1/admin: No such file or directory.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000e76: file src.c, line 17.
(gdb) c
The program is not being run.
(gdb)
```

Both gdb and gcc were installed using homebrew

```
| => which gdb
/usr/local/bin/gdb



which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

When I do a r, this is what I get

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/home/CTCI-C/Chapter1/1.1/src 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/corecrypto/corecrypto-233.1.2~26/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcorecrypto_static.a"
warning: `/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Objects/coretls.build/coretls.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/system_coretls_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_ciphersuites.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_handshake.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_record.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_stream_parser.a"

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffac8) at src.c:17
17      char* str= argv[1];
(gdb)
```

What is possibly going wrong here. Any pointers.

Comment: `c` == continue. `r` == run.

Comment: @Mat I've edited the post to include r

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Looks like it is working just fine.